# Как создать двумерный массив в Dart

Tags: dart

Как создать двумерный массив при помощи generate
Пробовал вот так: var twoDList = List.generate(4, (i) => List(5), growable: false); не работает
Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Двумерный массив в *dart* - это массив массивов и создавая его генератором нужно одновременно создавать вложенные массивы. До недавнего времени допускалось использование конструктора [List()](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/List/List.html), но в последних версиях языка этот конструктор не работает, т.к. создаваемый массив заполняется значениями **null**, а в новой спецификации обычный массив не может содержать пустые значения. В документации рекомендуется замена на [List.filled](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/List/List.filled.html):

```dart
var twoDList = List.generate(4, (i) => List.filled(5,0), growable: false);
```

В некоторых случаях могут помочь вложенные генераторы

```dart
var twoDList = List.generate(4, (i) => List.generate(5, (j)=> i*5 + j, growable: false), growable: false);
```